# How to put an interface constraint on a generic method in C# 3.5?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, constraints

I want to achieve something like this in C# 3.5:

```
public void Register<T>() : where T : interface {}
```

I can do it with class or struct, but how to do it with an interface?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096568/how-can-i-use-interface-as-a-c-generic-type-constraint

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use interface as a C# generic type constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096568/how-can-i-use-interface-as-a-c-sharp-generic-type-constraint)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# and the CLR don't support overall interface constraints, although you can constrain it to a particular interface (see other answers). The closest you can get is 'class' and check the type using reflection at runtime I'm afraid. Why would you want an interface constraint in the first place?

Comment: For custom/crazy implemented dependency injection, maybe. But that's me guessing.

Answer (score 14):

If you are asking about adding a constraint to a specific interface, that's straightforward:

```
public void Register<T>( T data ) where T : ISomeInterface
```

If you are asking whether a keyword exists like class or struct to constrain the range of possible types for T, that is not available.

**While you can write:**

```
public void Register<T>( T data ) where T : class // (or struct)
```

**you cannot write:**

```
public void Register<T>( T data ) where T : interface
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't demand that T is an interface, so you'd have to use reflection at runtime to assert this.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I went with a solution like this. It only works if you want several specific interfaces (e.g. those you have source access to) to be passed as a generic parameter, not any.

- I let my interfaces, which came into question, inherit an empty interface `IInterface`.
- I constrained the generic T parameter to be of `IInterface`

In source, it looks like this:

- Any interface you want to be passed as the generic parameter:

  ```
  public interface IWhatever : IInterface
  {
      // IWhatever specific declarations
  }
  ```
- IInterface:

  ```
  public interface IInterface
  {
      // Nothing in here, keep moving
  }
  ```
- The class on which you want to put the type constraint:

  ```
  public class WorldPieceGenerator<T> where T : IInterface
  {
      // Actual world piece generating code
  }
  ```