# Generic passing of interface and class implementing interface

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create a method that through generics tries to pass an interface and a class.
It should look something like this, but this does not build:

```
public static void Register<TInterface, TClass>() 
  where TClass     : TInterface 
  where TInterface : interface // <- doesn't compile
{
   ...
}
```

Is there any way to get this to work. The idea is to build a wrapper around an ioc container.

Comment: There is not `where T : interface` constraint in c#, you can use only interface name. You can use something like that `where TClass : class, TInterface`

Comment: Why do you want to put *constraint* `: interface`? What's *wrong* if I provide, say, *abstract class* for `TInterface`?

Comment: No. You can't constrain type parameters to interfaces. In general, if you find your generics wanting to impose constraints like this, it's typically a sign you've gone too far, as there's not much meaningful you can do with the knowledge. It's just "lining up types nicely" for appearances' sake.

Comment: This looks like you're implementing a sort of "poor man's dependency injection". Take a look at how other mature container implementations do it, they will have something like `void Register<TService, TImplementation>() where TService: class where TImplementation : class, TService`

Comment: There is similar kind of question in stack overflow as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104229/how-to-put-an-interface-constraint-on-a-generic-method-in-c-sharp-3-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it the way you want.
The closest you will be able to achieve is by limiting `TClass` to inherit/implement the `TInterface`, but `TInterface` can also be a class (and TClass can also be an interface. Perhaps its worth noting that `class` does not mean `class` but any reference type. It can also be an `interface`)

```
public static void Register<TInterface, TClass>() 
  where TClass     : class, TInterface
  where TInterface : class
{

}
```