# Specify generics where T should be interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I was thinking of a generic method where T should be interface but it can be the descendant of IFace

```
public static T Get<T>(SomeClass foo) where T : IFace {
  if(smthing)
    return Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);
}
```

so i can call

```
Class.Get<IFace>(smth)
Class.Get<IFaceDescend>(smt)
```

but not

```
Class.Get<Class2>(smt)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use interface as a C# generic type constraint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096568/how-can-i-use-interface-as-a-c-sharp-generic-type-constraint)

Comment: @ken2k oh yes, i did not find it, wasting my time asking :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do this. You can test for it at execution time:

```
if (!typeof(T).IsInterface)
{
    throw ...;
}
```

... but you can't express it as a compile-time constraint on `T`.

Comment: @Zavael see my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9164633/385844) to the duplicate question for an approach that allows you to avoid checking `typeof(T).IsInterface` every time the method is called.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible in current C#.

The only thing you can do is to validate the fact on runtime, using something like

```
if (!typeof(T).IsInterface) throw new ArgumentException("T must be an interface");
```

(Note that there is no `TypeArgumentException` which might be a better choice, I guess.)