# Object must implement IConvertible when trying to return a tuple

Tags: c#

At runtime I get the following error

> "Object must implement IConvertible"

calling function

```
lboxBuildingType.SelectedIndex = pharse.returning<int>xdoc.Root.Element("BuildingTypeIndex").Value);

public static T returning<T>(object o)
{
       Tuple<bool, T, object> tmp;
       switch (Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)))
       {
        ////blah blah blah
           case TypeCode.Int32:
              tmp= (Tuple<bool,T,object>)Convert.ChangeType(I(o.ToString())), typeof(T)); // error
              break;
        ////blah blah blah
       }
}

private static Tuple<bool, Int32, Object> I(object o)
{
      int i;
      bool b;
      Int32.TryParse(o.ToString(), out i);
      b = (i == 0);
      return new Tuple<bool, Int32, object>(b, i, o);
}
```

The aim of the code is to pass in a `<T>("15")` and have it produce a `tuple<Bool,T,object>` which would be `tuple<true, 15, "15">`

It errors out where I have marked it with a // error

Comment: You could use the generic type constraint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096568/how-can-i-use-interface-as-a-c-sharp-generic-type-constraint

Comment: Use an List<> object instead of a Tuple<>.  The List<> object has a built in method for IConvertible.

Comment: @Sven Generic type constraints wouldn't solve this problem.

Comment: If you are checking the type of a generic then you're almost always doing something wrong.

Comment: @jdweng That would just change the error from one to another; even if he had an `IConvertible`, the object he's trying to convert it to isn't one that `IConvertible` supports.

Comment: What you should really have here is different methods/overloads for each type you want to support, rather than using generics and checking the type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ConvertType` is a method that lets you convert objects implementing `IConvertable` into one of a fixed set of objects (strings, numeric types, etc.)  Not only is it not able to convert any `IConvertible` object into any type of `Tuple` (If you look at the methods of that interface you'll see why.) but the `Tuple` that you're calling it on isn't `IConvertible` as the error message is telling you.

Of course, the solution is to just not call `ChangeType` in the first place.  It exists to convert objects from one type to another, but *the object you have is already of the proper type*, you just need to inform the compiler that the compile time expression should be different, and that you know that the type will always match at runtime.  You do this with just a regular cast:

```
tmp = (Tuple<bool,T,object>) (object) I(o.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This. This ignores "Object must implement IConvertible" error for example GUID:

```
public object ChangeType(object value, Type type)
    {
        if (value == null && type.IsGenericType) return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        if (value == null) return null;
        if (type == value.GetType()) return value;
        if (type.IsEnum)
        {
            if (value is string)
                return Enum.Parse(type, value as string);
            else
                return Enum.ToObject(type, value);
        }
        if (!type.IsInterface && type.IsGenericType)
        {
            Type innerType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            object innerValue = ChangeType(value, innerType);
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { innerValue });
        }
        if (value is string && type == typeof(Guid)) return new Guid(value as string);
        if (value is string && type == typeof(Version)) return new Version(value as string);
        if (!(value is IConvertible)) return value;
        return Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
    }
```