# Why does a Generic<T> method with a "where T : class" constraint accept an interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, constraints

I have this `interface`:

```
public interface ITestInterface
{
    int TestInt { get; set; }
}
```

and this generic method (with a `T : class` constraint):

```
public void Test<T>() where T : class
{
    // DoSomething
}
```

and this call:

```
Test<ITestInterface>();
```

and everything compiles and runs while an `interface` **is not** a `class` (or is it?).

Why does this happen?

I first saw this on my WCF proxy class:

```
public partial class TestServiceClient:
     System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TestNamespace.ITestService>, TestNamespace.ITestService
```

where `ClientBase<T>` has this definition:

```
public abstract class ClientBase<TChannel> : 
     ICommunicationObject, IDisposable where TChannel : class
```

Comment: See answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096568/how-can-i-use-interface-as-a-c-sharp-generic-type-constraint

Comment: An interface is not a class, but it is a contract, a promise what a class looks like. So where you have a declaration with an interface, the calling code should use an instance of an object that implements that interface.

Comment: @o_weisman - Thanks man..couldn't find that on google.

Comment: @GolezTrol - I know. I just saw that on my WCF proxy client and created a simple example. I know there are better ways to achieve something like this. Thank you.

Comment: @o_weisman, The `class` constraint is to verify that only reference types will be used as the generic argument. Now, since value-types *can* implement interfaces it leaves us with the question, how can the compiler be sure that it's not a value-type that is implementing that interface?

Comment: @haim770 - just checked that - The compiler will show a non-reference type error if you use a struct implementation.

Comment: @AmirPopovich But if you cast the `struct` to the interface type, it will compile.

Comment: @AmirPopovich, See https://gist.github.com/chaim770/8986b8fdd587c9a32b2b

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - I'm talking about the Test<StructThatImplementsInterface> call. I tried to create the method using MakeGenericType and it gave me this exception:

    GenericArguments[0], 'WindowsFormsApplication1.ABC', on 'Void Test[T]()' violates the constraint of type 'T'.

Comment: @haim770 - OK..Now I understand your case. I was looking into the non-argument scenario..

Comment: `class` and `struct` seem like odd choices of keyword for this in retrospect, it; it *is* a little confusing.  Maybe it would have been more appropriate to use something like `ref` or `val`, since that's what is *actually* being filtered on.  That ship has long since sailed though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `class` constraint means that the type must be a reference type, not necessarily a class.

From C# language specification:

> The reference type constraint specifies that a type argument used for the type parameter must be a reference type. All class types, interface types, delegate types, array types, and type parameters known to be a reference type (as defined below) satisfy this constraint.

Basically, it means that the type cannot be a value type.

Value types can implement interfaces too, but casting a value type to an interface causes the value to be boxed

```
IComparable i = 0;
```

Now `i` stores a reference to a boxed `0`.