# Generic type constraint for interface?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, generic-constraints

I can do this:

```
void MyMethod<T>() where T : class { }
```

Is there anything like this?

```
void MyMethod<T>() where T : interface { }
```

I'd prefer not to specify the interface name explicitly.

The alternative is that I can pass in an argument that's constrained by `class` and throw an exception if `typeof(T).IsInterface` returns false, but that's not as clean as a constraint.

Comment: This sounds like a solution to an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you show more about what you're trying to solve by wanting to do this?

Comment: What's the purpose of such a constraint?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use interface as a C# generic type constraint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096568/how-can-i-use-interface-as-a-c-sharp-generic-type-constraint)

Answer (score 2):

This makes no sense since it doesn't leads to any limitations.

Constraint `class` means that the type argument must be a reference type.

So what `interface` without explicit interface name should limit?

Interface itself is just a declaration of methods/properties, so constraint "something is interface" literally mean "something has some declarations" - that is useless.

Comment: You know what, you're right.  There can be no instance of an interface, so nothing will ever be passed in that is `only` an interface.  If only I could delete this question.

Comment: All interface types must be reference types.

Comment: Answer is wrong: it would limit `T` to be an interface type. So `MyMethod<IDisposable>()` or `MyMethod<IEnumerable<string>>` would work fine, whereas `MyMethod<string>()`would not work.  OP is right, this constraint does not exist in C# right now. But the real question is: would such a feature be really useful? I can't think of a use case.

Comment: @Falanwe This answer is actually correct.  Interfaces can't exist as instances alone.  Another class must implement the interface in order for it to have any substance outside of a contract definition.  I was originally looking for a way to enumerate all types in my assembly and get the ones that implemented specific interfaces.  I will need to pass in a series of types and then validate that they're interface types and throw an exception otherwise.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin : no, it's not correct. An object can't be an instance of an interface alone, but we're not talking about instantiating an object here, but about specifying a generic, and you can specify it to an interface. regular use of Linq frequently does so in fact. For instance `var emptyDisposableEnum = Enumerable.Empty<IDisposable>();` works fine, the method gets specified to the interface, but no "raw" interface instance is ever created of course (because such a thing is obviously not possible).

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: another use case that frequently arises is when you are using some IoC (for instance [Autofac](http://autofac.org/)). In that case, you will often call `scope.Resolve<IMyContract>()` and get some instance implementing `IMyContract` without knowing what is the concrete type of the instance you receive. And most of the time, you just don't care.

Comment: @Falanwe I second, it is an incorrect answer. There're even real cases where it is necessary. For example if you want to proxy an instance implementing certain interface - with interface type as T you can be certain that you can proxy everything just fine. But if someone provides sealed class there or class with non-virtual methods - the code will fail miserably at runtime.

Comment: The answer is wrong by claiming it doesn't make sense. It does. Sometimes you want to be able to only pass an interface type, creating proxies is a common case for that. In fact I see the possibility for any possible type attribute being useful as a type restriction, like you may want to restrict a type parameter for non-sealed classes so you can guarantee at compile-time you will be able to generate a descendant class programatically. Many reflection code is riddled with condition guards that exists only because of a lack of more flexible generic type constraints.

Comment: Answer is wrong. it does make sense. generic constraints are there to let us know of contraints during compile time. consider `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IPerson>(data)` (assume no custom converters). granted this is the inverse of what the OP is asking, nevertheless it would be great if there was a way to differentiate classes and interfaces in generic constraints.