# Force T as reference type in code [CS0452 Error]

Tags: c#, generics, interface, reference-type

I have the following Problem with the T and the option for generic methods to restrict it to be e.g. a reference type (where T : class). So I got the following code:

```
public void mySave<T>(string filename, T obj)
{
    Session s = connect(filename);
    s.Save(obj);
}
```

with

```
public Document Save<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
```

there is no way to declare `mySave where T : class` because I get it from an interface. Anyway I need to solve `CS0452 (The type 'type name' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'parameter name' in the generic type or method 'identifier of generic')`

Any Ideas on doing that?

Comment: Either you've to sacrifice some type safety and use reflection or add the constraint in interface too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sriram suggested two ways... The more correct way (explored by Matías Fidemraizer) is to change the interface. The other way is through reflection. I support fully the way explored by Matías Fidemraizer, and think that it is the "right" way. But sometimes you can't do what is right, and you have to do what works.

This is the other way, through reflection. Note that this code goes further than necessary, caching the delegate so that further calls with the same `T` type won't need to reuse reflection and will be faster.

```
public static class SessionHelper
{
    public static void Save2<T>(this Session session, T obj)
    {
        SessionHelperImpl<T>.Save(session, obj);
    }

    private static class SessionHelperImpl<T>
    {
        public static readonly Action<Session, T> Save;

        static SessionHelperImpl() 
        {
            MethodInfo saveT = (from x in typeof(Session).GetMethods()
                                where x.Name == "Save" && x.IsGenericMethod
                                let genericArguments = x.GetGenericArguments()
                                where genericArguments.Length == 1
                                let parameters = x.GetParameters()
                                where parameters.Length == 1 && parameters[0].ParameterType == genericArguments[0]
                                select x).Single();

            MethodInfo save = saveT.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));

            Save = (Action<Session, T>)save.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<Session, T>));
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
s.Save2(obj);
```

Note that if you try to pass a non-reference type as `obj` you will get a `TypeInitializationException`. You can't really bypass the `where T : class` of the `Save`. You can only bypass it during compilation time and delay it to runtime.

Answer (score 4):

If some generic parameter has some constraints, any other generic parameter used as argument must, at least, provide same type guarantees.

Since generics are a compile-time feauture, just imagine that `Save<TEntity>` requires `TEntity` to be a reference type, and you could give an argument that may or may not be a value type. This would defeat the purpose of generics.

Your best bet is adding the whole generic constraint (i.e. `T : class`) to the interface too.

Comment: so it is not possible in any way to check this hardcoded? Like `if (typeof(T).IsClass){check here and call s.Save<T>}{else Error}`?

Comment: @pytomaniaq Well, it's possible with reflection (or `dynamic`). But as Matías noted, it kind of defeats the purpose - you lose the compile-time type safety. Why would you want to do that, rather than ensuring the interface itself is constrained?

Comment: @Luaan Yeah, BTW I prefer to don't provide the reflection way, because the question is just if it's possible to solve the issue (without modifying the interface) and the answer is "no"

Comment: @pytomaniaq If you went with the other answer (the reflection way), IMHO I find it a design flaw...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I just selected this Answer because it is the more related one regarding the question. Indeed your answer is the better one from a design view, and i managed to change the interface, but not for one who is searching for my question.

Comment: @pytomaniaq BTW, "more related" is subjective. Actually, any future visitor to your Q&A won't expect a reflection approach to solve the issue

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer but the Reflection is a working method for solving the problem, even if not using this is in most cases the better way.

Comment: @pytomaniaq Reflection isn't meant to implement workarounds. It has its use cases and it's very powerful

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer that's know to me, but what is your point?

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer I was looking for, taken from this post:
[How can I use interface as a C# generic type constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096568/how-can-i-use-interface-as-a-c-sharp-generic-type-constraint)

`where T : class, IProfile, new()`